# Full Text Search Using MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, search

The MongoDB structure is a **title** paired with a **body**. I have used:

```
$c = $this->db->find(['text' => ['$search' => $search_word]]);
```

but it is only searching the titles for the search word. I want it to search both the title and the body for the search word.